# tikz-cd: error stating I can only use specific letters for \arrow command, even when I use the correct letters

Tags: errors, tikz-cd

I am having trouble beginning to use the tike-cd package for commutative diagrams.  Whenever I use the \arrow or \ar command for an arrow, I come up with the errors:

"! Package tikz-cd Error: Arrow direction argument must only contain the letters u, d, l, r.See the tikz-cd package documentation for explanation".

"! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/r' and am going to ignore it.  Perhaps you misspelled it.See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation."

I have looked over the documentation for tikz-cd, and that was of no help, and I don't understand the second error; I tried to look up pgfkeys for help, and tried to import it into the document but still come up with the same error.  Am I wrong to assume all the packages I need in the preamble to use tikz-cd is just tikz-cd?  An example of a document that does not compile ,and returns this specific error, is:

```
\documentclass[11]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

I am using texmaker.  Originally thought I had miktext (I have always used this on my windows machines), but found I haven't installed it.

Solution: Installed an updated version of MacTex and used Tex Live Utilities as @egreg recommended.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example compiles fine for me (`11` should be `11pt`, however). I suspect a spurious character in your source; try retyping the whole line containing `\arrow[r]`.

Comment: As a sidenote, MiKTeX on Mac sounds strange. MiKTeX is a TeX distribution for Windows. Just out of curiosity, are you running MiKTeX in a virtual machine or with Boot Camp, and why?

Comment: @egreg : Unfortunately that didn't work.  Because it compile d fine for you, could it be a problem outside of the '\arrow' command or package and instead with texmaker that I'm over looking?

Comment: Another possibility is that your version of `tikz-cd` is old and doesn't support that syntax. In the `.log` file you should have something like `tikz-cd 2014/03/08 v0.9b Commutative diagrams with tikz`; please report what you find there.

Comment: @mvkorpel : perhaps that's my problem.  I installed texmaker a while ago, but now looking back I may have not installed miktex but something else.  I notice there is a similar question and the solution was a lack of what miktex does (the person asking was on windows).  If this is the problem I'll close my question.

Comment: @egreg : I definitely have an older version.  I found tikz-cd 2012/12/30 v0.3c Commutative diagrams with tike.' in the '.log' file.  I suppose I have to get the updated version and use that.  I will report if this works.

Comment: @JohannMiller You probably have MacTeX; you should download the 2014 version from `http://tug.org/mactex` and install it. Then run “TeX Live Utility” (that you find in the Applications folder) for getting the most recent updates.

Comment: @egreg You're right I am!  My mistake for the confusion.  Once I'm finished downloading and installing I'll update the package.

Comment: Thank you @egreg that was the problem.  It compiles correctly now!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to an outdated version of the software.

Comment: @JohannMiller I voted for closing this question as off-topic; don't worry, it's just for keeping the information as tight as possible. We're waiting for other contributions from you, either questions or answers. Welcome again!